# IoT DevKit MXChip AZ3166: ERROR: base64_utility.c (ln 201): Invalid length Base64 string

Tags: azure, connection, cloud, iot, devkit

Did you resolve this issue?

When my IoTDevKit is connected to the wifi. It repeats a message no-stop (see below).

I fallowed the step-by-step Microsoft Procedure *"GetStarted - Connect IoT DevKit AZ3166 to Azure IoT Hub"*

**I took the ConnectionString from this command:**

```
az iot hub device-identity show-connection-string --hub-name YourIoTHubName --device-id MyNodeDevice --output table
```

I tried with the connection located in Iot Device Explorer... and same result.

**And i used this connection string format:**

```
HostName={YourIoTHubName}.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=MyNodeDevice;SharedAccessKey={YourSharedAccessKey}
```

**This is the ERROR:**

> 2019-08-28 13:22:04 ERROR: base64_utility.c (ln 201): Invalid length Base64 string!
>   2019-08-28 13:22:04 ERROR: sastoken.c (ln 217): Unable to decode the key for generating the SAS.
>   2019-08-28 13:22:04 ERROR: iothub_client_authorization.c (ln 460): Failed creating sas_token
>   2019-08-28 13:22:04 ERROR: iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c (ln 2169): failure getting sas token from IoTHubClient_Auth_Get_SasToken.

The screen of my IoTDevKit still with the IP Adress and Running...
(under that, " > IoT Hub")

Did you have a solution for that? 
My connection string contains only 112 characters (with the Label "HostName=")
And... all worked fine the first day that I tried. The next day... this issue appears.

## version

**DevKitSDK version:** 1.6.2

**Mico version:** 31620002.049

**mbed-os version**: 5.4.3

**mbed TLS version:** 2.15.0

**WIFI version: wl0:** Sep 10 2014 11:28:46 version 5.90.230.10

[MXChipScreen Connected but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G05V.jpg)

[Error from Putty connected to the MxChip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvgcy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might run into this issue. I solved it on the current firmware by using this guide (https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/use-configuration-mode/) to first get the DevKit into configuration mode and from there I entered the connectionstring with the "set_az_iothub" command in PuTTY.